# Selecting all columns in a cell array that contain a certain value in the first row?

Tags: matlab, cell

I currently have a 4x3500 cell array. First row is a single number, 2 row is a single string, 3rd and 4th rows are also single numbers.

Ex:

```
1    1    2   3   3   4   5   5   5   6
hi   no   ya  he ........ % you get the idea
28   34   18  0   3 ......
55   2    4   42  24 .....
```

I would like to be able to select all columns that have a certain value in the first row. *ie* if I wanted '1' as the first row value, it would return

```
1    1
hi   no
28   34
55   2
```

Then I would like to sort based on the 2nd row's string. *ie* if I wanted to have'hi', it would return:

```
1
hi
28
55
```

I have attempted to do:

```
variable = cellArray{:,find(cellArray{1,:} == 1)}
```

However I keep getting:

```
Error using find
Too many input arguments.
```

or

```
Error using ==
Too many input arguments.
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't have MATLAB to  test this. You can create a vector from the first row by doing `vec = [cellArray{1,:}]`. Now, do `ind = vec == 1`. You now know which columns to extract from your cell array. Does this work then: `cellArray{:,ind}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` indexing will return a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which will provide *multiple* outputs. When you pass this to `find`, it's the same as passing *each element of your cell array as a separate input*. This is what leads to the error about to many input arguments.

You will want to surround the comma-separated list with `[]` to create an array or numbers. Also, you don't need `find` because you can just use logical indexing to grab the columns you want. Additionally, you will want to index using `()` to grab the relevant rows, again to avoid the comma-separated list.

```
variable = cellArray(:, [cellArray{1,:}] == 1)
```

Comment: That's fantastic, worked perfectly! Just a quick question for my own knowledge: why are we allowed to use '()' for a cellArray instead of having to use '{}'?

Comment: @aboublemc `{}` gets an *element* out of a cell array whereas `()` returns a cell array that contains certain elements. If you get multiple values with `{}` it will return an output for each of the values.